# Как из телеграмм бота переслать сообщение в чат

Tags: telegram-bot

У меня есть телеграмм бот где пользователи отвечают на вопрос с вариантами ответов, но получается что на вопросы они отвечают, а ответ знает только пользователь. Как мне сделать чтобы эти ответы приходили в чат или личным сообщением?

Comment: `bot.send_message(chat_id, message_id)`

Comment: Во-первых и последних... В настройках бота (BotFather в помощь) выставить необходимые разрешения , после чего загнать бота в чат или канал и выдать ему необходимые права, после чего слать сообщения в соответствующее место.